# How can I stop Adsense scripts from conflicting with Wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, adsense

Ever since I got my Adsense account approved and placed google ads on my site "[nowviba](http://www.nowviba.com)", none of my other plugins that use scripts have been able to work. For example, I have an mp3 player plugin that I placed on my homepage but it doesn't show up in my browser at the same time with my Google Adsense ads. I have already tried to manually use script code instead of shortcodes to display the plugins but no success. How can I resolve this?